# For variable voltage devices, namely SD cards, how much power do you save by using a lower voltage?

Tags: microcontroller, switch-mode-power-supply, low-power, camera, sd

I'm designing a computer vision system and my 3 main components are

1. microcontroller   (VDD = [1.8V, 3.6V])
2. microSD card (4 bit mode, VDD = [2.7V, 3.6V] according to SD 2.0 standard)
3. cheap cell phone camera (using the 8 bit parallel DVP interface, VDD = [1.8V, 3.0V], Vanalog = [2.6V, 3.0V])

I suppose using lower voltages will reduce power, but I'm starting to doubt this because I found all the components have an internal switched capacitor regulator that change the voltage further (1.3V for the microcontroller, 1.5V for the camera, and probably a high voltage for the microSD). So, using a lower voltage will just result in a higher current draw. The only exception is for the camera, whos [datasheet](http://www.dragonwake.com/download/camera/ov5642/OV5642-DS.pdf) says it uses a **linear** regulator to drop the external DOVDD (I/O voltage) to the 1.5V digital core. In that case, I can save (2.7V - 1.8V) * 0.1A = 90mW by using 1.8V instead of 2.7V. This is about a 15% power saving for the whole system.

Currently, I can get away with using 2.7V for all my components. I'm only working on this as a hobby and only have a 1 layer PCB, so I'm hesitant about using multiple voltages.

So my questions are:

1. How much core/internal power does using a lower external voltage save? None?
2. How much I/O power does using a lower voltage save? I'm aware from Bill Dally's [presentations](http://www.nvidia.com/content/pdf/sc_2010/theater/dally_sc10.pdf) that data transfer often consumes more power than computation, but I'm not operating at GHz speeds. According to the camera data sheet, table 8-3, when you don't use the internal regulator for generating the 1.5V core voltage, the I/O current, Idd-do is only 9-12 mA, so using a lower swing wouldn't save much power.
3. How do you use the 1.8V mode on SD cards? Initially, you need to operate at 2.7 - 3.6V. After sending a CMD5 requesting 1.8V, then you can drop to 1.8V. But this seems hopelessly complicated to me? That means I need to drop the voltage to the micro controller too, right? and do it gradually. Are there any regulators that allow smooth transitioning from 2.7V to 1.8V?

Comment: Rule #1 about voltage vs. power saving: P=E²/R

Comment: It's not so much the voltage a device is operated at, but the clock frequency.  Microcontrollers are often rated at so many  µA's (or mA's) per MHz.  This is why they have so many sleep modes.  I assume SD cards would be the same, they can be run off of an SPI bus anywhere from several hundred kHz to 40 or so MHz, a 100:1 ratio.  I would guess there would be at least an order of magnitude power savings over that range.

Comment: @Ignacio, silicon isn't an ohmic material, so E^2/R doesn't apply, only P = V * I.

I'm expecting a much more in depth answer that considers the efficiency of the switching regulators used. Yesterday, I found that voltages closer to the internal core voltage of a device are more efficient for capacitative regulators (charge pumps) because it means less energy is wasted in charging/discharging the capacitor.

Comment: @tcrosley - I will optimize the clock speed, but for now, let's assume it's already minimized.

Answer (score 1):

Circuits that have a switch mode power supply (either a DC/DC converter, or a switched capacitor regulator) will not change the total power consumption significantly as the input voltage changes.

Circuits that don't include a pre regulator will generally consume less power when powered by a lower voltage. When you reduce the voltage, most digital circuits will reduce their current proportionately, so the overall power will decrease as V^2 (lower V and lower current will both reduce power). Analog circuits are generally biased differently and while the power will reduce, the current may remain the same. That is still lower power.